# Why is there no float center in CSS?

Tags: css, css-float

I have found that there is no float center in CSS and I was a little disappointed.  However, I can't help but ask myself why.  While many people want to use this for centering content I wished to use it to float a bunch of blocks into rows on a dynamic page size.  Unfortunately without a float center it looks sloppy as there is extra space (whatever fraction of a full block doesn't fit) on one side.  It makes me sad that the intended use of floats is hurt by this property missing.

I can't see a reason why there isn't a float center and was wondering if anyone had reasons, either technical or otherwise why a float center was not included in the standard.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you've done that looks bad?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kevincox/rAkNY/3/ Is pretty much the story.  If the window isn't a multiple of the box size the whole thing looks off kilter.

Comment: if you know the exact sizes of your boxes and numbers per row thats an easy fix.

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rAkNY/4/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no float center because floats take elements out of the content flow and position them as far left/right as possible. floats by themselves only move things sideways. not 100% on this last part, but i reckon it has something to do with print. i know the idea of floats was taken from the print industry.

Comment: You could define center as halfway between the far left and right although this makes me think about interactions with left and right floats.  That could be hard to define.

Comment: not so much...they are made specifically to go "as far left or right as possible"....as also pointed out, floated elements are taken out of the content flow, positioning them automatically in the center is impossible...the content wouldn't be floating around it

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using `float: left`, use `display: inline-block` on the individual elements and center their container.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/rAkNY/5/

Comment: working around backwards compatibility and graceful degradation

Answer (score 4):

Yes, There is not Float center/middle and may the W3C having the answer.

There is `<center>` tag but no-longer.

> The `<center>` tag is deprecated as of HTML 4, and using it creates a
>   few different issues. HTML centered elements can display differently
>   in different browsers, and using the  tag can increase page
>   load time. Also, heavy use of  will complicate your site
>   redesigns — removing hundreds of  tags takes a lot longer than
>   changing one style rule in a stylesheet.
>
> The  tag was officially deprecated many, many years ago, but
>   it is still recognized by most browsers through their
>   backward-compatibility features. So yeah, if you  something,
>   it'll be centered. However, in the interest of future-proofing you
>    should use modern CSS centering
>   methods instead.

Use `margin:0 auto;`

If you're centering something else, margin: 0 auto; will get your element centered most of the time. (Quick note: your element must have a declared width for this to work.)

> The margin: 0 auto; rule is shorthand for 0 top and bottom margin, and
>   automatic left and right margins. Automatic left and right margins
>   work together to push the element into the center of its container.

Comment: margin auto does not work for "true" floating use, because the elements are treated individually.  If you restrict the container to "snap" sizes in increments of the contents you can center the full rows but the partially-full rows will still be off to one side.

Comment: @KevinCox : show the issue to us make a fiddle or give the link to the webpage...

Comment: In both chromium and firefox on my machine that displays as a single line of elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center contents:
1. set css property **display: inline-block** or **inline** to each content item.
2. set css property **text-align:center** to their parent node.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to use CSS it needs only HTML. `<center>` tag will make it's child elements to center.

Demo:

```css
div {
color: white;
padding: 5px;
}
#blueDiv {
background-color: dodgerblue;
}
#orangeDiv {
background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo - Center elements</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="orangeDiv">this div is not centered</div>
<br>
<center>
<div id="blueDiv">this div is centered!</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```